# null pattern and composite pattern don't play nice together

Tags: design-patterns, composite, null-object-pattern

In this composite tree I am keeping a reference to the parent node for flexible tree traversal.  I don't want to have to check the parent for a null reference all the time but if I make a NullNode class and initialize each node's parent to this I get a stack overflow since the NullNode has a NullNode has a NullNode has a.... ad infinitum
I've tried setting the NullNode's parent to null but then I still have to do a null reference check for the parent which seems to defeat the purpose.
anyone run into this?  What, if anything can be done?

thanks!

Comment: How does your traverse function work?  You need to stop somehow? You need to post some code, because your question doesn't seem valid.

Comment: I never even get far enough to search the tree.  The stack overflow happens during construction of the NullNode since it contains a parent that is initialized to NullNode.

Comment: The NullNode certainly should have NO PARENT AT ALL. See the second answer below with the pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I make a NullNode class and initialize each node's parent to this I get a stack overflow since the NullNode has a NullNode has a NullNode has a.... ad infinitum I've tried setting the NullNode's parent to null but then I still have to do a null reference check for the parent which seems to defeat the purpose. anyone run into this?

Your `NullNode` doesn't need to actually contain another `NullNode` as parent.  Just implement `getParent()` in `NullNode` (or whatever you're calling it) to return `this` or `self` or whatever means that in your language.

However, this may still be a bad idea, as you *do* have to stop the traversal at some point.  The above gets you past the constructor recursion, but there's no root for the tree as it's NullNodes all the way up or turtles all the way down or something like that.

This will all be much easier to talk about if you actually show the code even though it's not working, and describe your plans for usage a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Counter example (extreme pseudo code):

```
class NullNode(): Component{
   public NullNode(){

   }
    public something SearchUp(){
       return null;
    }
}

class Node: Component{
   public Node(t){
       this.parent = NullNode();
   }
    public void SetParent(Component parent){
       this.parent = parent;
    }
    public something SearchUp(){
      return self.parent.SearchUp();
    }
  }

abstract class Component{
    Component parent

    public Component(){
    }
    public something SearchUp();
 }
```